# Compact an external Access (.accdb) database

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007, vba

I have tried many codes to do this task, and none of them seems to work, anyone can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved question myself by looking at some online reference, if anyone needs it here it is:

Dim oApp As Object

Set oApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")

oApp.DBEngine.CompactDatabase SourcedDatabase, DestDatabase

Kill SourcedDatabase

Name DestDatabase As SourcedDatabase

Set oApp = Nothing